# QComboBox.addItems: called with wrong argument types

Tags: python-3.x, método, pyside, pyqt

Tenho o seguinte codigo:

```
self.option = QComboBox(self)
self.option.addItems(self.getJson)

def getJson(self):
    self.data = {'image' : ['planet.jpg', 'cat.png', 'building.jpg']}

    return self.data['image']
```

Quero fazer com que o retorno da função `getJson` vá para o `QComboBox` que criei, no entanto,ao rodar o código, aparece essa mensagem de erro:

> TypeError: 'PySide.QtGui.QComboBox.addItems' called with wrong
>   argument types:
>   PySide.QtGui.QComboBox.addItems(method)

Como faço para o `addItems` receber o retorno do método sem dar esse erro?

Comment: o retorno do `getjson` não deveria ser uma string json?

Comment: e não é? Meu codigo estava assim: 
self.option = QComboBox(self)
self.data = {'image' : ['planet.jpg', 'cat.png', 'building.jpg']}
self.option.addItems(self.data['image'])

Comment: Atenção à resposta do @zekk em baixo, acho que resolve o problema

Comment: Eu vi @Miguel , mas estou querendo deixar modularizado o codigo.

Comment: Eu acho que sei o que se está a passar, ora tente isto `self.option.addItems(self.getJson())` . Faltavam os parentesis acho eu

Comment: deu! obrigado @Miguel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Segundo a [documentação](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qcombobox.html#addItems), é esperado uma lista, você está passando uma função.

Passe a lista diretamente:

```
self.option = QComboBox(self)
self.data = {'image' : ['planet.jpg', 'cat.png', 'building.jpg']}

self.option.addItems(self.data['image'])
```

Uma outra forma é colocar o resultado da função numa variável e passá-la ao `QComboBox`:

```
self.option = QComboBox(self)
self.json = self.getJson()

self.option.addItems(self.json)

def getJson(self):
    self.data = {'image' : ['planet.jpg', 'cat.png', 'building.jpg']}

    return self.data['image']
```

Comment: Eu tinha feito assim, até aí, tudo certo, mas estou querendo modularizar o codigo, deixando funções específicas pra cada caso..

Comment: @AlexandreMartinsMontebelo Veja se outra forma atende o teu caso.

Comment: Consegui, no caso faltou apenas o parentesesnda chamada à função getJson dentro do addItems, aí deu certo ;)